# customizing url mapping of multiple sites in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, url-mapping

So, I want to customize my mappings of urls to home pages inside Sitecore

my sites home pages are nodes like this (below /sitecore/content):

```
/FOO/us
/FOO/ca
/FOO/..other countries
/BAR
```

i Want to reach them by the following urls:

```
mysite.com/us -> /FOO/us
mysite.com/ca -> /FOO/ca
mysite.com/bar -> /BAR
```

my sites declarations are like this

```
<site name="FOO-US" virtualFolder="/us" physicalFolder="/us" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/FOO/us" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
 <site name="FOO-CA" virtualFolder="/ca" physicalFolder="/ca" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/FOO/ca" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
<site name="BAR" virtualFolder="/bar" physicalFolder="/bar" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/bar" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
```

However, i never get the expected url resolution, mostly i get 404 or get to the default Home node.

i'm testing this multi-site configuration in sitecore (6.5) in my local IIS (both 6.0 and 7.0 versions with no luck). Is that possible?

Comment: I don't have sitecore in front of me, but you possibly could do this by having two site definitions with the same hostname attribute (mysite in this case).  Then, you would place a `virtualFolder='/bar'` in the entry on top (because I think sites are resolved top to bottom).  Then, you might get what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get this to work out of the box because they're all on the same hostname (mysite.com). You can get it to work if you set the startItem to FOO and put bar underneath it. Then all three separate "sites" would be immediate children of the root (FOO). E.g.

```
/Foo/us
/Foo/ca
/Foo/bar
```

Comment: is there a way to implement this maybe with a custom HttpRequestProcessor or ItemResolver?

Comment: Yes, it would most likely be a custom `ItemResolver` in the `HttpRequest` pipeline. You might need to tweak where it calls `GetItem()` from the `args`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the default 'website' definition? (you probably should). You may be able to do this by juggling the root and startItem paths, perhaps :

```
rootPath="/sitecore/content/FOO" startItem="/us"
rootPath="/sitecore/content/FOO" startItem="/ca"
rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/bar"
```

or maybe (untested) :

```
rootPath="/sitecore/content/FOO/us" startItem=""
rootPath="/sitecore/content/FOO/ca" startItem=""
rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/bar"
```

If these are just vanity urls rather than seperate sites, then leave the config as one site and use redirects (use one of the redirect modules) instead.