# sitecore site gives error

Tags: web, sitecore, sitecore6

Does Sitecore have some sort of hardcoding regarding the `website` default site? i changed it to be called something else and i just keep getting 'Length cannot be less than zero`

```
<sites>
      <site name="shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/login" content="master" contentStartItem="/Home" enableWorkflow="true" enableAnalytics="false" xmlControlPage="/sitecore/shell/default.aspx" browserTitle="Sitecore" htmlCacheSize="2MB" registryCacheSize="3MB" viewStateCacheSize="200KB" xslCacheSize="5MB" />
      <site name="login" virtualFolder="/sitecore/login" physicalFolder="/sitecore/login" enableAnalytics="false" database="core" domain="sitecore" />
      <site name="admin" virtualFolder="/sitecore/admin" physicalFolder="/sitecore/admin" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/admin/login.aspx" />
      <site name="service" virtualFolder="/sitecore/service" physicalFolder="/sitecore/service" />
      <site name="modules_shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" content="master" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" />
      <site name="modules_website" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/web" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/web" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" />
      <site name="foo" virtualFolder="/us" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/foo/us" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
      <site name="scheduler" enableAnalytics="false" domain="sitecore" />
      <site name="system" enableAnalytics="false" domain="sitecore" />
      <site name="publisher" domain="sitecore" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" />
    </sites>


<cacheSizes>
      <sites>
<foo>
          <html>10MB</html>
          <registry>0</registry>
          <viewState>0</viewState>
          <xsl>5MB</xsl>
        </foo>
      </sites>
    </cacheSizes>
```

I verified that the size is accessible going to http://localhost/?sc_site=foo . The site should be resolving when doing http://localhost/us, but i just get this meaningless error

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I remember, Sitecore needs to know how to map your hostname (localhost) to it's site name (foo).  Therefore, you have two options available.

1) map foo to localhost in your hosts file (and then browse http://foo/us)

2) add a hostname attribute to the foo site definition in sites config and use the value 'localhost'

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Try to take the virtualFolder attribute off:

```
<site name="foo" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/foo/us" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
```

Then, with `127.0.0.1       foo` in your host file, browse just `http://foo`.

Comment: i've done that; updated system32/drivers/etc/hosts and then added hostName attribute to the node, and still getting the same error

Comment: Do you have any host entries in you IIS config?

Comment: what IIS config? i opened up the site properties in IIS manager, and my web site tab has tcp_port 80 and IP address unassigned, you mean something else?

Comment: Do you see a * under the hostname column in IIS bindings (IIS7), or a * next to the declaration of port 80? If you set up the website using defaults, then you should be fine.  Just running through the things I'd start to look at.

Comment: What did you update the hosts file to? (127.0.0.1 foo).  Did you then try to browse with just `http://foo`

Comment: 127.0.0.1 localhost \n 127.0.0.1 foo \n

Comment: try just foo, not local.foo.test.  If you do local.foo.test, then you would have to browse `http://local.foo.test/`

Comment: yes sorry i meant foo but i wrote local.foo.test, still no luck.

Comment: With foo in the hosts file, can you set up a test.html file in the root of the website and browse that `http://foo/test.html`?

Comment: yeah i get the test.html. Also i'm even able to access the actual webpages in sitecore passing the sc_site parameter in the url query

Comment: Yeah, because it works with sc_site it points directly to sitecore not being able to resolve the hostname to the site for some reason.  I've made another suggestion in the answer.

Comment: Cool. I think the virtualFolder meant that what you were actually trying to browse was `http://foo/us/us`.  BTW, if you want to have the url be `http://foo/us` then try and change the physicalFolder attribute to '/foo/' (take off the /us).

Comment: i made a small modification, made the physical folder equal to the virtual folder and now it works. but i added a new site node and it has the same problem

Comment: this is related to a wider problem in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235595/customizing-url-mapping-of-multiple-sites-in-sitecore/9240977#comment11640530_9240977 however i've accepted your answer for this problem